# Save \n symbol in the string (JS)

Tags: javascript, json

I've API method that returns rsa key like this:

```
"publickey" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0G
CSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC5WleAVeW5gySd
QVFkTi44q1cE\ncWDT2gmcv2mHcWhwI/9YqGV2LqpMASe
4t4XS/88fvTTHafHn1KaL9F7d73T9k4cp\nm+YxKJexkK
/wOxf/NZBieoADaLLaU1+OoPauSw3i4DZxKqIm1nxNHSV
LUfyY44gN\nClVxtZzW/nwdWEdSQwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
```

However, when I get this publickey and write it to some variable at the client,

```
var key = data.publickey
```

there're no `\n` symbols in the `key` variable, but I **need them** for proper document signing.

Can I somehow keep `\n` in the string?

Comment: They need escaping, `\n` -> `\\n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ben said, you'd have to escape the escape (`\\`). So, in total, it would look like:

```
\\n
```

Comment: So in the server I need smth like `key.replace(/\n/g , "\\\n");` ?

Comment: I think that should work. It's worth trying just to be sure.

Comment: @AlexJohnson If I am not mistaken here, that is one backslash to many. It should be only one extra backslash, e.g. `key.replace(/\n/g , "\\n");`, to preserve a single backslash. And the `n` doesn't need anything but being an `n`